# Divide returns 0 instead of float

Tags: c#

I was very surprised when I found out my code wasn't working so I created a console application to see where the problem lies and I've got even more surprised when I saw the code below returns 0

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float test = 140 / 1058;
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I'm trying to get the result in % and put it in a progress(meaning (140 / 1058) * 100) bar on my application,the second value(1058) is actually ulong type in my application,but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

The question is - where the problem is?

Comment: i don't get 0..i get 0.1323251

Comment: Unedited the code since the edit to add the float cast make the question totally useless!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work the way you expect ...

```
float test = (float)140 / (float)1058;
```

By the way, your code works fine for me (prints a 0.1323251 to the console).

Comment: The original question didn't have the float cast on the first number and hence it was doing integer division.  The modified code works as you noted.

Comment: so now the question is irrelevant since there is no bug in it.

Answer (score 9):

You are using integer arithmetic and then converting the result to a float. Use floating-point arithmetic instead:

```
float test = 140f / 1058f;
```

Comment: @enrikkallen,I'm sorry,I forgot to mention I get the second value from a function,which returns ulong type(in my application) ,how do I add that "f" in the end of the ulong variable?

Comment: cast it from a ulong to a float by putting (float) in front of the function result before you divide.

Comment: However, if it's ulong you probably want to convert it to double instead to prevent precision loss.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are dividing integers and not floats.  Only the result is a float.  Change the code to be the following

```
float test = 140f / 1058f;
```

**EDIT**

John mentioned that there is a variable of type ulong.  If that's the case then just use a cast opeartion

```
ulong value = GetTheValue();
float test = 140f / ((float)value);
```

Note, there is a possible loss of precision here since you're going from ulong to float.

Comment: I'm sorry,I forgot to mention I get the second value from a function,which returns ulong type(in my application) ,how do I add that "f" in the end of the ulong variable?

Answer (score 2):

The division being performed is integer division. Replace

```
float test = 140 / 1058;
```

with

```
float test = 140f / 1058;
```

to force floating-point division.

In general, if you have

```
int x;
int y;
```

and want to perform floating-point division then you must cast either `x` or `y` to a float as in

```
float f = ((float) x) / y;
```