# Problem In OutPut Of Divided Number

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Divide problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904780/divide-problem)

Why does c# show the output of this code as 0??

```
 MessageBox.Show((5/6).ToString);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`5/6` is basically *integral division*, which turns out to be `0`. The type of both operands is `int`.

I think what you want is :  `5.0/6.0`.

In fact, `5.0/6.0`, `5/6.0`, `5.0/6`, all would give same result. That is, as long as, one operand is `double`, it would be a *double division*, and the type of the result would be `double` as well.

Answer (score 6):

Because unless you specify that you want the operation to result in a `Double` the operation results in an `Integer`, and so the fractional result is dropped and you are left with just the whole number of 0.

Answer (score 3):

It is dividing an integer by and integer and will return an integer, I believe it always returns the floor value.  Try `Messagebox.Show((5.0/6.0).ToString());`

Comment: You are perpetuating the incorrect syntax. :x

Answer (score 2):

Because you are doing integer division. If you want non-integer division you should do something like 5 / 6d

Answer (score 2):

The compiler assumes that the numbers are Int, which must be whole numbers. Thus, it is rounding the answer. To return the decimal answer, use this:

```
MessageBox.Show((5d/6d).ToString());
```